# Dynamically sort div by ID from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I have drag&drop DIVs on my angularjs 
web app.
The user can sort div or check on checkbox to add new div, based on the div position I take DIVs ID's and send an array to API, so when the user came back again, there is everything like he was sort.
This is what I send to API and this is ok

```
["D", "A", "C"]
```

Problem is when a user came back, I get from API array and I need to sort everything like in response array. Response is same like send array. This is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="dragulaBox" 
dragula='"sixth-bag"'>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="A" ng-if="A">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="B" ng-if="B">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="C" ng-if="C">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="D" ng-if="D">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="E" ng-if="E">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="F" ng-if="F">
</div>
</div>
```

For this, I don't use `ng-repeat` because I have checkboxes for add new div.

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="A" value="A" ng-checked="A" ng-
model="A")"><label>A</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="B" value="B" ng-checked="B" ng-
model="B")"><label>B</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="C" value="C" ng-checked="C" ng-
model="C")"><label>C</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="D" value="D" ng-checked="D" ng-
model="D")"><label>D</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="E" value="E" ng-checked="E" ng-
model="E")"><label>E</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="F" value="F" ng-checked="F" ng-
model="F")"><label>F</label>
</div>
```

I make code to show the only DIV with ID from the array, but I don't know how to sort exactly like an array. 
Can someone help me with sorting div?

### Thnx

edit:
I try this with directive like in answer bellow but this is not working

```
app.directive("arrangeDiv", function(){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, atts ){
        element.sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
            return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
        }).each(function () {
            var element = $(this);
            element.remove();
            $(element).appendTo("#dragulaBox");
        });

    }
  }
 })
```

and in parrent div I pass array in directive atribute

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="dragulaBox" 
  dragula='"sixth-bag"' arrange-div="poredakGrafova"></div>
```

This is array in response from API
["B","F","E","D"]

Comment: One a side note, the `DOM` is wrong, there is no opening tag for `label`!

Comment: Oh sry, I cleaned up the code to put it here so I delete it wrong. I fix this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/ would help you

Comment: @KhatamNaayak I don't get it how to sorting exactly like in my array by ID. Thank you

Comment: So you want to `filter` divs and then `sort`?

Comment: User check checkboxes for select DIVs with a chart. And with drag&drop he changes a position of divs how he likes. I take the DIV positions in order and send to the API. Once the user returns to the web app, Everything needs to be set up as the user has set last time (as in the array)

Answer (score 3):

**jquery div sort easy:--**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="res">
  <div id="3">text 3</div>
  <div id="4">text 4</div>
  <div id="1">text 1</div>
  <div id="2">text 2</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#res div").sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
    return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
}).each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.remove();
    $(element).appendTo("#res");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Yep, if you don't use ng-repeat, there is no way to sort it with angular. But you can wrap this solution in directive ,apply it to parent object and pass your array as attribute value. It'll be more angular way. `my-sort-divs="array"`

Comment: @kindzoku can You pls help me to wrap this to directive? Thnx

Answer (score 1):

**Angular js sort this way:--**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
 return function(input, attribute) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

    var array = [];
    for(var objectKey in input) {
        array.push(input[objectKey]);
    }

    array.sort(function(a, b){
        a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
        b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
        return a - b;
    });
    return array;
 }
});

myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.orderByAttribute = '';
    
    $scope.testData = {
        123: {name: "Test B", position: "2"},
        456: {name: "Test A", position: "1"},
        789: {name: "Test C", position: "3"}
 };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
        <button ng-click="orderByAttribute = 'position'">Order by Position</button>
        <button ng-click="orderByAttribute = ''">Use order in object</button>
        
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in testData | orderObjectBy:orderByAttribute">
                {{item.name}} (Pos: {{item.position}})
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx, this is a very nice solution but I need to use this without ng-repeat. I make directive like you suggest.. .but not working... I put code here

Answer (score 1):

**Without ng-repeat using in Angular js:--**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  {{item}}  
     <div class="reason-content">
           
           {{item[0].id}} <br>
           {{item[1].id}} <br>
           {{item[2].id}} <br>
           {{item[3].id}} <br>
           
           {{item[0].name}} <br>
           {{item[1].name}} <br>
           {{item[2].name}} <br>
           {{item[3].name}} <br>
           
          </div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', function ($scope, filterFilter) {

  $scope.foobar = [
    {"id": 15, "name": "bar1"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "bar2"},
    {"id": 215, "name": "bar3"},
    {"id": 7415, "name": "bar4"}
  ];
    $scope.item = filterFilter($scope.foobar);
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is filterFilter here?

Comment: These are predefine function of angularjs